# interdependent classes in same namespace problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I'm in a real fix... I need to port code, which has a lot of interdependent classes and uses namespaces in order to avoid includes. This works in **MSVC**, but I can't find a way to deal with this situation in **GCC** :(

Contents of **myString.h** file:

```
#include "baseBuffer.h"
//I can't forward declare a base class, so I have to include its header

namespace test
{
    class MY_ALLOCATOR
    {
        static const unsigned int LIMIT = 4096;
        class myBuffer : public BaseBuffer<LIMIT>
        {
//...
        }
    };

    template <class T, typename ALLOC = MY_ALLOCATOR> class myContainer
    {
//...
    }

    typedef myContainer<char> myString;
}
```

Contents of **baseBuffer.h** file:

```
#include "myObject.h"
//#include "myString.h"
//I can't include **myString.h**, because it includes this header file and I can't seem to find a way to use forward declaration of **myString** class...

namespace test
{
    template <uint limit> class BaseBuffer : public MyObject
    {
        public:
            myString sData;
//...
    }
}
```

**Please help!**

Comment: You just have to sort it out. A myString (aka myContainer) can't reasonably use a BaseBuffer to allocate its space, if that uses a myString as base for the storage.

Comment: How do you "use namespaces to avoid includes"?

Comment: And why would you want to avoid them? They are essential to the C++ separate compilation model.

Comment: These all are good questions, but the problem is this is not my code...

Comment: can you post a small but compilable subset of your files that exhibit this problem (compiles on MSVC but breaks on GCC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing guards in your header files.

MSVC most likely allows you to do that through an extension. Therefore, there are two ways how to solve this :
1. the 1st solution is to merge those two headers.
2. the 2nd solution is forward declare template class myContainer, and create it dynamically in the basebuffer.hpp (instead of `myString sData`, create `myString *sData`)

**EDIT**
Add a cpp file for baseBuffer, and include that instead of the header file. In the header forward declare template class myString, and in the source you can include whatever you like.

Comment: MSVC supports `#pragma once`, which is probably the customary way of doing so. That said, I don't see those statements in his code either...

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure there are no other options?

Comment: Cody, #pragma once won't help in this case because of circular dependency. And don't mind the guards, I guess I shouldn't have omitted them...

Comment: @Ryan Forward declare is standard way of avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'll have to use the first solution you mentioned.